# Missing 1 required positional argument, Recursion - Python

Tags: recursion

```
def times(n,k):
if k >= 1:
    return times(k-1) + n

times("140",3)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\insane 18\Desktop\mat.py", line 21, in <module>
    times("140",3)
  File "C:\Users\insane 18\Desktop\mat.py", line 19, in times
    return times(k-1) + n
TypeError: times() missing 1 required positional argument: 'k'
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

i keep getting this error even though i am putting the value of k but still getting this. please help me

Answer (score 1):

Your `times` function takes two arguments as per your definition, namely `k` and `n`. However, when yyou recursively call the function `times` you're just supplying one argument(`k`) and not the other (`n`).

If you change your code to the following, it works.

```
def times(k, n):
    if k<=1:
        return times(k-1,n) # n has been moved inside the parentheses.
```

As a general guideline: Python doesn't have Tail Call Optimization and it is advised to avoid recursive calls.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused because you gave only one argument when you called times in line `return times(k-1) + n`